# How can make the first link color default "red" when the page loads

Tags: jquery

Please see the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/B5dYv/5/

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#stickyheader a').on('click', function() {
         $('.active').removeClass('active');
         $(this).addClass('active');
     });
 });
```

How can I make the first link (discography) default red when the page loads and then it turns grey when any other link is clicked?

Answer (score 1):

Add this line after your click handler:

```
$('#stickyheader a:first').addClass('active');
```

Or add `class="active"` to your discography link in the HTML so the page loads with the appropriate class. This way it doesn't have to wait for the JavaScript to add it.

Answer (score 1):

Add `.filter(':first-child').addClass('active').end();` to your event binding to use the power of chaining (and remove the need for jQuery to re-query the DOM :)

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#stickyheader a').on('click', function() {
        $(".active").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    }).filter(':first-child').addClass('active');
});
```

Updated JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/B5dYv/94/